# Stop Video Pop Up showing related videos

Tags: wordpress, video

I am using wordpress video popup([link](http://beta.your30secondpitch.com/)) for playing YouTube videos but, after completion the video it is showing related videos on YouTube. I donot want to show related videos at the end of the video it needs to change pause state.This is the [link](http://beta.your30secondpitch.com/) I have used for video popup.How can I stop showing related videos? please provide any links or suggessions

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162380/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-posts-without-adding-suggested-videos-at-the-end

Comment: Is there any free links for video popup without related youtube videos

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `?rel=0` at the end of your video URL.

**UPDATE**

If you go to the website of the wordpress plugin you can see that there is a limitation.

http://wp-time.com/video-popup-plugin-for-wordpress/

You have to install  [Extend Link Plugin](http://wp-time.com/extend-link-plugin-wordpress/) and there you find that **a premium attribute** `rel=”1″` to disable YouTube related videos is necessary.

Comment: Is there any other way

Comment: Is there any free links for video popup without related youtube videos